# Shared libraries versions and executables on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, versioning, executable

Let's describe the following scenario:

---

I intend to create an application for the **Linux** platform

The application will contain a core shared/dynamic **library** and the **executable**. The library will act like an engine, providing common and essential classes and functions.

Now, I know that both the library and executable may change over time and I want to make sure that each executable knows what library is for it and in case the library version is different it will show a message about the library being two old (this could be a constant, abiding by the ABI rules, that will always contain the version and will be checked against the executable's version at the beginning of the entry point).

I have read the ABI specifications and rules and I don't like them (too strict). I don't want to have a single library on the user's system, which I update and try to keep compatible with older executables. I prefer, because I don't know how the interface will change and I want to reserve myself the freedom of doing any change later, to have each executable with its own library version on the user's machine. For example:

- Today the user has downloaded the executable "MyApp1" and the version *1.0.0* of the library "MyCoreLib".
- One week later I created a new application based on a new version of the library. The user downloads the version *1.1.0* of the library "MyCoreLib" and a new executable called "MyApp2". So, we have 2 different executables and two different versions of the same library (the same name).
- "MyApp1" should still be linked to the version *1.0.0* of "MyCoreLib" while "MyApp2" should be linked to the new version *1.1.0*.
- One week later I create a new application based on the older version *1.0.0* of the library. As the library already exists on the user's computer then we will use that.
- Now we have two executables using the first version of the library and one executable using the newer version, and so on.

---

In Linux, we have the version numbers at the end of the **.so** libraries. Does this give us the possibility to have multiple versions of the same library and **each executable linked to its own library version**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a entry point:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: This is what I don't get: *"Thus, /usr/lib/libreadline.so.3 is a fully-qualified soname, which ldconfig would set to be a symbolic link to some realname like /usr/lib/libreadline.so.3.0. There should also be a linker name, /usr/lib/libreadline.so which could be a symbolic link referring to /usr/lib/libreadline.so.3."* This looks like, if I don't use RPATH to specify the exact version, the executables will always be linked to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Read up on SONAMEs and RPATH.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

The version 1.0 of your library should generally change only for incompatible API changes.